# Methods With Same Name as Constructor - Why?

Tags: java, oop

Why is the following allowed:

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo() { ... }
  public void Foo() { ... }
}
```

Is there ever a valid reason for naming a method the same as the class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My guess is that it's allowed because explicitly disallowing it would add another requirement to Java's identifier naming rules for very little benefit. Unlike, say, C++, Java always requires that constructors are called with the `new` keyword, so there's never any ambiguity about whether an identifier refers to a method or a constructor. I do agree that a method with the same name as its parent class is quite confusing at first glance, and it should be almost certainly be avoided. That said, I'm glad they chose not to further complicate the language by banning such methods.

Answer (score 15):

This is heinous.  I would not allow such a thing to survive a code review.

Answer (score 11):

The only valid reason - that I can think of - for utilizing this is if the parent class adds methods after you have written the child class:

```
interface Father { } // version 1.0

class Son implements Father {  Son ( ) { } } // version 1.0

interface Father { void Son ( ) ; /* new method */ } // version 2.0

class Son implements Father { Son ( ) { } void Son ( ) { } } // version 2.0
```

If you have no control of the `Father` interface, but do have control of the `Son` class, then you have to change `Son` somehow. You could

1. Change the name of the `Son` class
2. Break the relationship with the `Father` class
3. Add the `Son` method

If the `Son` class is a dependency of many other projects then #1 and #2 may be unacceptable, leaving you with no choice but to add the `Son( )` method.

This is a highly contrived example. You should never see such a thing in real code.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor has the same name as the class and falls under the Type namespace. Method namespace is distinct from Type namespace in Java. So this is technically allowed (and this is not overloading).

However, there isn't ANY valid reason to actually name a method the same as the class name. It will be considered as a very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see a valid reason for it.

C# provides a compiler error - "Member Names Cannot Be The Same As Their Enclosing Type"

It could be quite confusing, especially when using reflection to look at the composition of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The method's return value is defined as void, whereas the constructor has no return value, which makes them different and thus valid code. Why someone would want to do that, however, is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is that in constructors we pass the values at the time of the object creation of the class.so thats why the name of the constructor should be the same so that it can take passed values and initialized at the time of the object creation of the class.