# StackOverflowError No idea what is wrong

Tags: java, class, stack-overflow

I'm continuously receiving this error when trying to run my program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:752)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1001)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:109)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:69)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:92)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:100)
at serverProperties.<init>(serverProperties.java:164)
at exportProperties.<init>(exportProperties.java:8)
at serverProperties.<init>(serverProperties.java:162)
```

It only happens after trying to access a method from a certain class.

This is the main class:

```
public class serverProperties extends JPanel
{
    //Add classes
    exportProperties writeProperties = new exportProperties();

    //Assume I created the array sent to the exportProperties class

    public serverProperties()
    {
        CheckBoxListener checkListener = new CheckBoxListener();

        //Assume I created the check box and added the listener for it
    }


    private class CheckBoxListener implements ItemListener
    {

        public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event)
        {
            JCheckBox checkBox;
            checkBox= (JCheckBox)event.getSource();

            //Process check Boxes
            if (checkBox.isSelected())
            {
                checkBox.setText("Yes");
                writeProperties.exportFile(propertiesArr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the class accessed by the code above:

```
public class exportProperties extends serverProperties
{


    public void exportProperties(String[] args)
    {
        exportFile(args);
    }

    public static void exportFile(String[] propertiesArr)
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("Path/file.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outFile);

            //Loop through properties
            for (int i=0; i < 27; i++)
            {
                out.append(propertiesArr[i]);
            }
            //out.write("Test");
            out.close();

        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void importFile()
    {

    }


}
```

Once I remove the call to the exportProperties class the program work perfectly. 
With the error message, the last two lines

```
at exportProperties.<init>(exportProperties.java:8)
at serverProperties.<init>(serverProperties.java:162)
```

they repeat MANY times before it just ends.

I've googled, and googled, I've got no idea what is going on..
I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `serverProperties` class has this:

```
exportProperties writeProperties = new exportProperties();
```

... which creates an instance of `exportProperties`. But `exportProperties` extends `serverProperties`, to constructing an `exportProperties` will execute the above line *again*... and so it continues.

Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give very concrete help beyond "don't do that". I suspect you shouldn't be using inheritance here. (It's not clear why you're extending `JPanel` either... try to prefer composition over inheritance.)

(You should also fix your class names to follow Java conventions...)

Comment: "You should also fix your class names to follow Java conventions" - and in particular, avoid creating a method with the same name as the class, that is dangerous.

Comment: @Oak: True, I hadn't even seen that. I'm surprised it's even valid!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401444/methods-with-same-name-as-constructor-why ... the horror

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the response! I removed "extends serverProperties" and it works perfectly! Fantastic.