# Constructor name and class name are the same in Java. Why?

Tags: java

Please give me a logical answer of naming a **class** and **constructor** with same name. Why we cannot choose a different name other than class name for a constructor?

```
class Temp
{
   Temp()
   {

   }
};
```

Comment: You can refer this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401444/methods-with-same-name-as-constructor-why

Comment: The first dup isn't language-specific, and the second is for Java. This question deserves a good, separate answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the first dup isn't language specific, but the accepted answer quotes Stroustrup's explanation of his reasoning.

Comment: @Bohemian James Gosling didn't design C++. Bjarne Stroustrup did.

Answer (score 8):

Because this syntax does not require any new keywords. Aside from that, there is no good reason.

> To minimize the number of new keywords, I didn't use an explicit syntax like this:
>
> ```
> class X {
>     constructor();
>     destructor();
> }
> ```
>
> Instead, I chose a declaration syntax that mirrored the *use* of constructors.
>
> ```
> class X {
>     X();
>     ~X();
> ```
>
> This may have been overly clever. [The Design And Evolution Of C++, 3.11.2 Constructor Notation]

Answer (score 7):

Constructor name being same as class name is simply a convention. A logical one too - consider the objects could be constructed like this also

```
Temp t = Temp();
```

It might have been called `constructor()` but then if you are looking at only snippet you wouldn't know what is it constructing?

Comment: +1, it would be very confusing if one could write `Temp t = SomeOtherName()` but still mean Temp

Comment: Well, the syntax would probably be `Temp t = Temp::foobar();` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard which defines the C++ language, a constructor *does not have a name*, at least not in the sense of an identifier which becomes declared by a declaration (a *declarator-id*). It is an anonymous function declared with a particular syntax, and referenced only under certain circumstances by more special syntax. In other contexts, the same term `Temp::Temp` refers to `class Temp` itself.

The constructor is declared using a member declaration naming the immediate *injected-class-name*. It may be referenced by an injected-class-name or other type-name used with the `::` punctuation (a *nested-name-specifier*) in the form `type::type`, with the last two `::`-delimited parts being the same token, in particular contexts such as delegating and inheriting constructors.

The reason for all this is that you cannot take a reference to a constructor, such as to get a function pointer to it or call it without creating a new object. Constructors are intrinsically tied to object lifetimes.

Historically, constructors evolved from factory functions, which returned initialized object of a given type. This pattern, where function names may alias types and constructors are merely convention, may still be seen in some languages. The current syntax evolved from something like what you might see in JavaScript. Some early C++ compilers (thinking about THINK C, not sure about earliest versions of Cfront) did not treat constructors as members at all.