# cant make constructor even if using same name method

Tags: java

I made two classes to try to understand class extension. here are the two classes I have

first one is main

```
public class main extends Ok {
    public static void main (String arg[]) {
        new Ok();
    }
}
```

And then I have Ok class

```
public class Ok {
    public void Ok(){
        System.out.println("k");
    }
}
```

I get the warning "Ok is never used". Why?

Comment: You are instantiating an `Ok` object but you never kept a reference to it.

Comment: You're creating a new void method not a constructor... Remove `void`. Also don't name your classes as `main` it may cause problems because of `main` method.

Comment: remove void from constructor

Comment: @Frakcool You're allowed to name a method the same thing as the class?!

Comment: @DavidEhrmann You're allowed to, but it's not recommended. See [Methods with same name as constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401444/methods-with-same-name-as-constructor-why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new `void` method not a constructor... Remove `void`. Also don't name your classes as `main` it may cause problems because of `main` method.

```
public class Ok {
    public Ok(){
        System.out.println("k");
    }
}
```

Like that, so it's a constructor not a `void` method :)

Class extension is called [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) too.

Imagine we're talking about `Mamals` (this is our class name) but we know all `Mamals` **are** (important word to remember) an `Animal`.

We know all `Animal`s can `eat()`, `pee()` and `appeal()`.

When you write class `Animal`:

```
public class Animal {
    public void eat() {...};
    public void pee() {...};
    public void appeal() {...};
}
```

And then write the class Mamal:

```
public class Mamal extends Animal {
}
```

It will have all the methods from `Animal` class except if they're `private`

For more information about inheritance you can read [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm) provided by @JorgeCampos on the comments below (Thanks!)

Comment: I would add more information to the answer since the OPs said `try to understand class extension` which means that just fixing this problem doesn't proper explain that.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yeah I'm thinking on how to explain it in plain english :)

Comment: Well, add a good link to it such this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Comment: @JorgeCampos see edit, I guess it helps a bit and might help the link you provided a little more :)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors have `no return type`, are `not inherited`, and cannot be hidden or overridden by `subclasses`.

Remove `void` and you will be good.