# How to call a function with some return type from function of Main class in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I am writing a java program to search a character/word in multiple files, so I am accepting the list of Keywords to search in command line argument i.e. String[] args, and I want to store there values in a ArrayList object.

I have main class name : **CharSearchTool**, Another class in same package : **ArrayListFromParameters**

```
package com.charsearchtool;

public class CharSearchTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayListFromParameters arrayList = new ArrayListFromParameters(args);
        System.out.println(arrayList.list);
    }
}




package com.charsearchtool;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListFromParameters {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> ArrayListFromParameters(String[] argument) {
        for (int i = 0; i < argument.length; i++) {
            list.add(argument[i]);
        }
        return (list);
    }
}
```

I am getting error on below line :

```
ArrayListFromParameters arrayList = new ArrayListFromParameters(args);
```

**Error : The constructor ArrayListParameters(String[]) is undefined.**

Comment: A constructor doesn't have a return type. It should be `public  ArrayListFromParameters(String[] argument) {` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: You've got a "pseudo-constructor".

Comment: It's because you haven't defined the constructor. There's just an empty no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned return type of the constructor.

You can write-

```
public ArrayListFromParameters(String[] argument) { for (int i = 0; i < argument.length; i++) { list.add(argument[i]); }  }
```

And that shall work.

Comment: Then why the below code is working :


public class CharSearchTool {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayListFromParameters arrayList = new ArrayListFromParameters();
  ArrayList<String> finalList = arrayList.ArrayListFromParameters(args);
                System.out.println(finalList);
 }
}

public class ArrayListFromParameters {
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 public ArrayList<String> ArrayListFromParameters(String[] argument) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argument.length; i++) {
   list.add(argument[i]);
  }
  return (list);
 }
}

Comment: As also mentioned in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3401487/5377141) , the new keyword is used for calling constructors. That helps to make it unambiguous. As in your question, you are trying to make a constructor call. And as in your comment, you are calling the method with the same name as the class name. In Java, yes, method names can have the same name as their class names. However, the way they are called differentiates them. At compiler level, constructor's return type becomes void.

Comment: P.S., never create any method having the same name as the class name. That code can not be seen in a production level code.