# Getting the "cannot find symbol" error in a Java program

Tags: java

```
package testing;

public class Clerk {
    private String name;
    private double score;
    private Clerk clerk;
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public double getScore(){
        return score;
    }
    public void setscore(double score){
        this.score=score;
    }
    public Clerk(String name, double score){
        this.name=name;
        this.score=score;
    }
    public void Clerk(String name, double score){
        clerk.add(clerk); //i am getting the error here
        
    }
```

The error stated is "cannot find symbol". I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Much help is appreciated.

Comment: Little more details required to solve your problem. Please explain when and how you are getting this error.

Comment: you need to define the add method in your class or your class variable clerk should be a list if you want to add something into it.

Comment: @BubbleGum Are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `add` in that class Clerk.
To make it compile add:

```
private void add(Clerk clerk) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no valid reason to name the method with the class name. As said here [Methods With Same Name as Constructor - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401444/methods-with-same-name-as-constructor-why) it will be considered a bad practice.
Try to rewrite your code like this:

```
public void setClerk(Clerk clerk){
    this.clerk = clerk;
}
public Clerk getClerk(){
    return clerk;
}
```